# SUSER_NAME() and CURRENT_USER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the difference between `SUSER_NAME()` and `CURRENT_USER`?

Comment: Can't you run both and see the difference between them?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja: Why multiple rows, it will never change within a Select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **[`CURRENT_USER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

  > This function returns the name of the current user. This function is equivalent to [`USER_NAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

It will return the UserName in the database.

- **[`SUSER_NAME([server_user_id])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

> Returns the login identification name of the user.

---

**Differences table:**

```
+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|             CURRENT_USER             |            SUSER_NAME([server_user_id])           |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Returns the name of the current user | Returns the login identification name of the user |
| No parameters                        | The paramater is optional                         |
| Return sysname                       | Return nvarchar(128)                              |
| No need to parentheses               | Must call it with parentheses                     |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

---

For example run this query and see the results:

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER, --or USER_NAME() parameter is optional
       SUSER_NAME(4) --parameter is optional
```

Comment: Well, the OP asked about `SUSER_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

`CURRENT_USER` returns the name of the current security context and expects no parameters. It is functionally equivalent to `USER_NAME()`

Whereas `SUSER_NAME()` will return the login identification name of the user - you can pass a `server_user_id` to return detail of the user or pass nothing to return detail about the current user.

Detail is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

You could run the following to see the differences yourself:

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME();
SELECT CURRENT_USER;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Current_User` will return the name of the user in the database whereas `SUSER_NAME()` will return the user name on the server. This is the major difference between the two. And as you can see Current_user has no arguments whereas SUSER_NAME() has.

Comment: `SUSER_NAME()` won't return just the `LogIn Name`, try `SELECT SUSER_NAME(4)`, it returns the login identification name of the user.